# Why is the `std::sto`... series not a template?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wonder if there is a reason why the `std::sto` series (e.g. `std::stoi`, `std::stol`) is not a function template, like that:

```
template<typename T>
T sto(std::string const & str, std::size_t *pos = 0, int base = 10);
```

and then:

```
template<>
int sto<int>(std::string const & str, std::size_t *pos, int base)
{
    // do the stuff.
}

template<>
long sto<long>(std::string const & str, std::size_t *pos, int base)
{
    // do the stuff.
}

/* etc. */
```

In my sense, that would be a better design, because for the moment, when I have to convert a string in whatever numerical value an user want, I have to manually manage each case.

Is there a reason to not have such a template function? Is there an assumed choice, or is this just done like that?

Comment: I presume by `std::sto` you mean `std::stoi`, `std::stol`, etc.?

Comment: The floating-point versions don't have a `base` parameter.

Comment: @erip yes, I will edit.

Comment: @Boiethios I think interjay's comment kind of answers the question.

Comment: There is probably something about remaining consistent with the "old" C functions that these functions call (`strtol`, `strtoll`, ...).

Comment: What would you gain from having to write `sto<long>` instead of `stol`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I have a class storing some config elements from file. I want the user could type: `Type myvar = myconfig.get<Type>("key");`

Comment: @Boiethios That's an extremely specific use case, and writing the templates you want yourself is trivial. (Shouldn't take more than minutes, I guess.) The C++ library is more geared towards generality than towards convenience.

Comment: @molbdnilo adding some wrapper around C functions takes also few minutes. My question is "why this way and not this other?".

Comment: I think @molbdnilo's comment hits the nail on the head: The arguments do not specify the specialization, so you would have to give the type argument explicitly anyway. That would only be useful in a templated use case. Additionally, a template in std:: was perhaps considered inappropriate because it  would give the impression of general applicability to any type, while in reality it is confined to numeric ones.

Comment: @Boiethios The purpose of these is to provide `strto*`-like functions for `std::string` rather than `char*`. Going the template path would make the common use case worse, not better, and it's not really generic anyway. You're also not allowed to add overloads to `std`, so you can't extend with your own types that need a different function prototype.

Comment: @molbdnilo: You are not allowed to add new overloads to `std`, but you ARE allowed to specialize existing `std` templates. Case in point, `std::swap` and `std::hash`.

Comment: @Boiethios In your `myconfig.get<Type>("key")` example, there's always [boost lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

Comment: See `lexical_cast` for the "neat" way. I was very surprized to learn that going through strstream stuff was much faster, due to templates and inlining, compared to the C function which was a ge eral purpose back end for several related functions, signed and unsigned, which requires branching.

Comment: @molbdnilo "What would you gain from having to write sto<long> instead of stol?"  The ability to use another template parameter or constexpr to determine which template to use, perhaps?  If you have a function template where the user specifies an integer type, and you have to use `strto*` to parse a string specifically into that type, it would be beneficial to just be able to pass it in, instead of either specializing your own, or doing `strtoll` or `strtoull` and casting down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`I have to manage manually each case. Is there a reason to not have such a template function?`

In case of such questions, Eric Lippert (C#) usually says something along the lines:

> If a feature is missing, then it's missing because noone implemented it yet. And that's because either noone else earlier wanted yet, or because it was considered not worth the effort, or because it couldn't have been finished before publishing the current release".

Here, I guess it's the "not worth" part, but I have neither asked the commitee about, nor managed to find any answer in old questions and faqs. I didn't spend much time searching though.

I say this because I suppose that most common of these functions' functionality (if not all of) is already contained in stream classes, like `istringstream`. Just like `cin`/etc, this one also has an all-having `operator >>`, overloaded for all base numeric types (and more).

Furthermore, the stream manipulators like `std::hex` (std::setbase) already solve the problem of passing various type-dependent configuration parameters to the actual conversion functions. **No problems with mixed function signatures** (like those mentioned by DavidHaim in his answer). Here's just a single `operator>>`.

So.. since if we have it in `streams`, if we already can read numbers/etc from strings with simple `foo >> bar >> setbase(42) >> baz >> ...`, then I think it was not worth the effort to add more complicated layers to old C runtime functions.

No proof for that though. Just a hunch.

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the [description of these functions at cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), I note the following:

> ... Interprets a signed integer value in the string str.
>
> 1) calls `std::strtol(str.c_str(), &ptr, base)`...

and `strol` a "C" standard function that's also available in C++.

Reading further, we see: (for the c++ `sto*` functions):

> #### Return value
>
> The string converted to the specified signed integer type.
>
> #### Exceptions
>
> - `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion could be performed
> - `std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type or if the underlying function (std::strtol or
>     std::strtoll) sets errno to ERANGE.

So while I have no original source for this, and indeed have never worked with these functions, I would *guess* that:

**TL;DR** : These functions are C++-ish wrappers around already existing C/C++ functions -- [`strtol*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) -- so they resemble these functions as close as possible.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with template specialization is that the specialization requires you to match the original template function signature, so each specialization must implement the interface of `(string,pos,base)`.

If you would like to have some other type which does not follows this interface, you are in trouble.

Suppose that, in the future, we would like to have `sto<std::pair<int,int>>`. We will want to have `pos` and `base` for the first and the second stringified integer. we would like the signature to be in the form of `string,pos1,base1,pos2,base2`. Since `sto` signature is already set, we cannot do it.

You can always wrap `std::sto*` in your implementation of `sto` for integral types, but you cannot do that the other way around.

Comment: couldn't that be workaround with variadic template in `c++11`?

Comment: you could do it even before with runtime polymorphism.  yet, I think it's a bit of overkill for converting function, most of the time you don't know the type embedded in the string on compile time. usually, string to XX conversion functions are used for parsing (CSV,XML,JSON etc.) so anyway your code will be split to handle seperatly integer, strings etc.

Comment: You're probably right, but still I would find it comfortable to have function symmetric to `std::to_string` even if they were templated...

Comment: well, honestly, I think the best thing for the standard is to throw away anything string-related and re-write it from scratch. `std::sto` is the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of these functions is to provide **simple** conversions for common cases. They are not intended as a general-purpose conversion suite. `std::ostringstream` is much better for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

> In my sense, there would be a better design, because for the moment,
>   when I have to convert a string in whatever numerical value an user
>   want, I have to manage manually each case.

No, it would not. Templates goal (deliberately setting T-MP apart) is **not** to replace overloading; you should always prefer overloading to templates. Actually, it's something the language *already* does for you! Between a candidate function and a possible template instantation, the former will be prefered. Using language features for the sake of it is bad.

I don't see how templates could help either. Whatever type the user decides to input, it won't be known till runtime, and template types are deduced at compile time. C++ is a statically typed language. In this case, templates will just add an unneeded layer of complexity over normal function overloading.

Comment: i agree with the sentiment, but overloading is not an option. you can't overload purely on the return type.