# Why is there no std::from_string()?

Tags: c++, getline, text-parsing, istream

Why is there no

```
template <typename T>
T std::from_string(const std::string& s);
```

in the C++ standard? (Seeing how there's an `std::to_string()` function, I mean.)

PS - If you have an idea for the reason this was not adopted/considered, just answer/comment and say what it is, rather than downvoting. I'm not actually making a proposal that this be included in the standard.

Comment: [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and family.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's not the same thing.

Comment: "[Why is the `std::sto`… series not a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920924/why-is-the-stdsto-series-not-a-template)" may be of interest.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*That's not the same thing.*" ... why isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. This question is well-posed and legitimate.

Comment: @einpoklum It is not exactly the same thing but a generic from string would be way to complicated considering all of the different sources and types you could convert to.

Comment: @NicolBolas: 1. A single templated function. 2. Not limitied to numeric types.

Comment: @Bathsheba: "*I don't understand the downvoting. This question is well-posed and legitimate.*" No, it's not. The answers will be *arguments*, not facts.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*1. A single templated function. 2. Not limitied to numeric types.*" [The `to_string` series are not template functions. And they are limited to numeric types.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) Note that you cannot add *overloads* to the `std` namespace.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The answers should be explanations of considerations which the standard committee has made.

Comment: @NicolBolas einpoklum is *looking for* a template that's not limited.

Comment: @einpoklum: Which would only be possible if they had *considered* a `from_string`. Do you know if any such proposal exists? Have you [done the research to find any such proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/)?

Comment: @Quentin: "*einpoklum is looking for a template that's not limited.*" He claims that there should be a "from_string" because there is a "to_string". But `to_string` is not the inverse of his suggested `from_string`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That's not quite searchable. I searched around some, and did not find such a discussion, so I figured that there was some "obvious" reason I was missing. I also remember searching for from_string here on SO before, and it occured to me now that an answer explaining why it doesn't exist could be helpful to people.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I can see your opinion, and I guess mine differs from yours. That's the beauty of the voting system. But I was concerned about the net -3 at the point of my first comment.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree with you, as I want to know the answer and have found this question. -3 sounds to me hilariously wrong. Fortunately, it is at least positive at this moment.

Comment: @YongweiWu: My answer is hovering on the brink ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As Nicol Bolas pointed out, `to_string` is never a template, but just a group of overloaded functions. Making such functions templates are not good, as doing them generically is probably not efficient, and can only behave like stringstreams. So `from_string`, similarly, should not be function templates, but rather simple functions. Since their argument is the same type (`std::string`), their names should not be the same. So `stoi`, `stof`, and the like are really what you wanted.

`to_string` and `sto*` also behave similarly regarding the locale: they all respect the current C locale. The C++ IOStreams, on the contrary, are not affected by the C locale. They can be overridden only if they are created after the C++ global locale is set by `std::locale::global`, or are manually `imbue`’d with a different locale.

Answer (score 1):

`std::to_string()` has a much tighter mandate: it consists of a well-defined set of non-templatised overloads and each overload has a type that is trivially stringifiable. So it's easy to define *exactly* what the functions should do.

Your proposal of `std::from_string()` is far broader. It would have tricky corners such as error handling considerations, precision settings, etc. The already-available stream functions that do this kind of thing are probably sufficient.

Comment: Why would this be more tricky than what you have with operator>> and istreams?

Comment: The istream stuff has all sorts of modifiers for adjusting precision and radix - that would be difficult to encapsulate in a single function.

Comment: Your 1st paragraph is exactly what I thought when I saw this question, aside from too opinion-based/broad... so +1. My 2nd thought was that @einpoklum just wants [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html#boost_lexical_cast.examples.strings_to_numbers_conversion). And since the Committee frequently adapt things from Boost, there's a very good search term to use when assessing whether they have considered this, as was argued in the comments on the question.